# Publishing wso2 AM 1.9.0 events to DAS 3.0.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

We are evaluating the wso2 DAS 3.0.0, which is an evolution of BAM 2.5.0.
We are trying to publish AM events to DAS as we did following [1].

If I configure in the admin-dashboard/analytics of the AM the DAS address:

```
Event Receiver Group
{tcp://<DAS server>:7611}

Data Analyzer Configurations
https://<DAS server>:9443
```

I get

```
[2015-07-10 11:04:15,942]  INFO - add:jag Deploying BAM toolbox 'API_Manager_Analytics.tbox'...
[2015-07-10 11:04:15,983] ERROR - add:jag Error occurred while installing BAM Toolbox (Cause:org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) https://<DAS server>:9443/services/BAMToolboxDepolyerService)
```

How do I do it?
What do I have to configure on DAs to accept AM publishing?

Thanks
Alberto

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics

Answer (score 4):

Since APIM 1.9.0 is default support BAM, that UI is for deploy the BAM analytics artifacts called toolbox. When you work with DAS, you should leave Data Analyzer Configurations as blank.
And need to deploy artifacts(CaPP) manually on DAS.

you can refer this blog and solve it.

http://blog.rukspot.com/2015/09/publishing-apim-runtime-statistics-to.html

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify for new users... This information may not apply to integration b/w wso2 am 1.10.0 and das 3.0.1. First, wso2 doc says Data Analyzer Configurations cannot be blank; second, my experience is the apim car was deployed automatically.